# Laravel 5 bundles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bundles

I'm starting working with Laravel5 and I need to make app with some parts - e.g.:

```
admin.example.com
app.example.com
example.com
```

It means: in app will have registered users access, in admin, there will have access administrators and `example.com` will be for everybody.

I know, that this can be done in Symfony 2 via bundles, but I'm not sure, what's the best way to make it in Laravel 5.

Could you give me please your opinion about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel, bundles are called packages. You could also use a [custom package](https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules) to easily split your application into modules. [Here's](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-multi-app-or-modular-applications) the same question asked with some answers.

Hope this puts you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You can make hostname based routing using [route groups](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-groups). Using something like the following you can easily distinct between roles:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{type?}.example.com'], function()
{
    // .. do some logic based on type, eg change the controller
    Route::get('user/{id}', function($type, $user_id)
    {
        //
    });

});
```

Please note that this functionality is native to the core of Laravel.

Comment: Hm, seems good. And how could I separate app into three folders -> app, admin, website ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your comment is a follow up question based on the question asked here. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm trying to create three parts application -> with administration part, with app part (part for logged in users), and website part -> normally visible part, no need login...

Comment: You're still not explaining how the folders fit into your question. Are those physical folders on disk or vendor folders or .. ?

Comment: Thats, what I dont know, how to solve this in Laravel5. I need to create 3 parts app and I don't know, which way is the best one in Laravel